# Codename One - How to Store an Array of JSON data in Persistent Memory and Read it Back

Tags: json, codenameone

I have this JSON data that i receive as a response after sending a JSON request. I would like to store this data in a persistent storage memory or file and then read it back later and display in on my Screen as a dropdown List. I will appreciate if anyone knows how to it in Codename One.

```
    {
   result_code=0.0,
   data=   [
      {
         id=1,
         title=Afghanistan
      },
      {
         id=2,
         title=Albania
      },
      {
         id=3,
         title=Algeria
      },
      {
         id=4,
         title=Andorra
      },
      {
         id=5,
         title=Angola
      },
      {
         id=6,
         title=Antigua And Barbuda
      },      

   ],
   message=OK
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just did a small test (y)

```
String x = "{result_code=0.0,data=   [{id=1,  title=Afghanistan   },      {         id=2,         title=Albania      },      {         id=3,         title=Algeria      },      {         id=4,         title=Andorra      },      {         id=5,         title=Angola      },      {         id=6,         title=Antigua And Barbuda      },       ],   message=OK     }";
Storage.getInstance().writeObject("abcd.txt", x);
Object rawString = Storage.getInstance().readObject("abcd.txt");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rawString.toString());
JSONArray data = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
Double resultCode = Double.valueOf(jsonObject.getDouble("result_code"));
String message = jsonObject.get("message").toString();

// TODO: JSON parsing
JSONObject firstObjectFromArray = data.getJSONObject(0);
// TODO: do somestuff in a loop and put into combobox?
firstObjectFromArray.get("id");
firstObjectFromArray.get("title");
```

EDIT: which is the combobox component you are speaking of?

Comment: Hi Kaya, Thanks but it seems codename one does not have or support JSONObject library.

Comment: Oh, you may be right, but to your luck its now totally easy to get libraries into CN1 if you have the latest CN1 Plugin installed, i have eclipse for example. Update your plugin, then right click on your project -> CodenameOne -> CodenameOne Settings.

Another window will popup, select Extensions -> now install "Codename One JSON Library", afterwards do another right click on your project -> CodenameOne->Refresh cn1libs Libs.

Comment: That Sounds Great, I am new to CN1 and this is of great help to me, So i would like to loop through this data and display all of thedat on my screen at once as a list in a serialized way, do you have any idea how i can do this?

Comment: You could set the Text of a Label once with a Formatted String or make it the Hardway, with a List or even a Renderer for a List, therefore i would suggest to watch the Videos from Shai, theyre really not that bad.

Design your stuff in the Designer,(doubleclick on theme.res under /src) then save the file after you design your UI. Afterwards when you are in your StateMachine.java class, fetch the UI objects by calling the "findContainer" or "findButton1", findJSONLabel" (depends on your variable names you set them) and set their values.

Comment: Hi Kaya i get this error java.lang.ClassCastException: ca.weblite.codename1.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to ca.weblite.codename1.json.JSONArray on this line JSONArray data = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");

Comment: Hi Paul, i was out of office yesterday, i put the code right in my project and it works fine, i also cant understand why it is showing that error on that line. Did you change anything on the Given JSON?